# Tomcat: what server.xml connectors are required for a reverse proxy?

Tags: tomcat, alfresco, ajp

I having a working Tomcat app (Alfresco) on port 8080, which I instead need to run on port 443, forwarded from Apache (Apache is already handling lots of other SSL endpoints on this server).

This works, but I don't quite understand why. My setup is:

1. Apache with `mod_jk`. The connector handles URLs `https://example.com/alfresco` and `https://example.com/share`, which were previously explicitly on port 8080. `worker.properties` is set up to forward to port 8009
2. Tomcat's `server.xml` contains these connector definitions:

```
 <!-- Question: what is this for? -->
 <Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
        URIEncoding="UTF-8" connectionTimeout="20000"
        maxHttpHeaderSize="32768" redirectPort="8443"
        enableLookups="false" xpoweredBy="false" server="AlfrescoECM"
        maxParameterCount="1000"/>

<!-- Alfresco requires an HTTPS connection to Solr on port 8443 -->
<Connector port="8443" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
               SSLEnabled="true" maxThreads="150" scheme="https"
               ... 
               sslProtocol="TLS" />

<!-- Define an AJP 1.3 Connector on port 8009 -->
<Connector protocol="AJP/1.3"
           port="8009" redirectPort="8443"
           maxParameterCount="1000" secretRequired="false" />
```

**If I omit the connector for port 8080 this doesn't work:**

```
 INFO  [webscripts.connector.RemoteClient] [ajp-nio-127.0.0.1-8009-exec-3] Exception calling (GET) http://localhost:8080/alfresco/s/api/admin/restrictions?guest=true
org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connect to localhost:8080 [localhost/127.0.0.1] failed: Connection refused
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.connect(DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.java:156) ~[httpclient-4.5.13.jar:4.5.13]
...
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
```

Question: why do I still need a connector for port 8080? Shouldn't this all be handled by AJP?

**EDIT**

Just done some more debug on this, by running netstat/lsof/fuser to find out exactly what's going on on port 8080. Tomcat/Alfresco is listening on 8080, but `lsof` marks it as `CLOSE_WAIT`, so it's unused, and Alfresco should have closed it, but it hasn't.

I normally have Keycloak/Quartus running, and I had to turn to it off to run the test above. If I run with Keycloak, it actually talks to Apache on 8080, so 8080 *is* used, but not by Alfresco. In fact, Alfresco runs normally when Keycloak is running, despite the fact that Alfresco still thinks it's using 8080.

So, unless I've missed something, the obvious conclusion is that `server.xml` doesn't require an entry for 8080, and Alfresco is (slightly) broken.

Comment: What does your Apache `mod_jk` configuration look like?

Answer (score 1):

In your case the ajp connector on tomcats port 8009 is only used for end user requests coming from apache acting as a reverse proxy. If you need to handle end user requests on 443 you should define that on apache side only.
In case of Alfresco your connectors on ports 8080/8443 are used for inter component requests (ShareUI > Repository, Solr tracker > repository). Don't modify these connectors / keystores if you do not know what you're doing.
The other way around: you may config the connectors for 8080/8443 to listen on localhost only to force any end user request thru Apache.

Comment: Hi Heiko - still confused. In the original HTTP configuration, Tomcat/"share" talked to the *client* on port 8080. Are you saying that it *also* talks to the repo on port 8080, and so it still needs to use 8080 even in an HTTPS setup? Note that my HTTPS setup works, and *only* port 443 is open, for Apache. I understand the need for localhost ("closed") ports on 8009 (for the reverse proxy) and 8443 (for Solr), but not the need for port 8080.

Comment: By default, the independant webapp "share" (--> the user interface) talks to the webapp "alfresco" (--> the repository) via http/8080. By default 8080/8443 are open on all interfaces but since you have apache as reverse proxy, you could configure both ports to listen on localhost only to allow share to talk to the repository.

Comment: port 8080 is configured in share-config (share-config-custom.xml)